# Placements of divs, side columns and content

Tags: css

I have a site which has several different options for left and right containers and a centre.

- The left div is always the same size, however some times it's not shown.
- The right has 3 options, small, normal or wide. Only one rightside will be shown at once, but some times there's none.
- The center should adjust to the left as well as the right side taking up as much space as possible but not push the right div to a new line (as it does with width:100%)

Is this at all possible? Having a div just, doing what you want it to do without having to tell it how?

I made an example in Fiddle in case my explanation was unclear: http://jsfiddle.net/WDZFx/13/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do u want to do some thing like this [fiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshmipriya/WDZFx/19/)

Comment: Here the center div should occupy the balance width not a defined one.

Comment: krish , change the #center's definition to "max-width: 60%" in @lakshmipriya 's code. But, the div will shrink according to its content.

Comment: @xFortyFourx: its strange to play with that fiddle...

Answer (score 0):

Jennica, here's a sample http://jsfiddle.net/uQ4TH/ , but it has the same problem I mentioned earlier, the center one will expand only according to the contents, though the maximum possible will be 50%;

Comment: Hi all and thanks for your replies! As xFourtyFourx also mentioned the problem will be the content extending to full width, if left or right columns arent filled the content (centre) should be maxed out. I'm not sure how to do this still, atm my best option is to set the width in codebehind after checking if the side divs have content or not. Not a nice solution but it's the best one i've got so far

Answer (score 0):

Make use of percentages instead of specifying the individual widths for the left/center/right:

Modify your css as:

```
#Wrap { 
    width:100%; 
}
#Left { 
    width: 10%; 
    float:left; 
    background-color:pink; 
}
#Center { 
    width: 30%; 
    float:left; 
    background-color:beige; 
}

#Right { 
    width:60%; 
    float:left; 
    background-color:silver; 
}
```